# What does Symfony Framework offer that Zend Framework does not?

Tags: php, web-framework, zend-framework, symfony

I have professionally working with Zend Framework for about a year. No major complaints. With some modifications, it has done a good job. I'm beginning to work on a side project where I want to heavily rely on MongoDb and Doctrine. I thought it might be a good idea to broaden my horizons and learn another enterprise level framework. There seems to be a lot a buzz about Symfony. After quickly looking over the site and documentation, I must say I came away pretty underwhelmed. I'm woundering what, if anything, Symfony has to offer that Zend doesn't? What would the advantage be in choosing Symfony?

Answer (score 2):

Though ZF2 will probably support Doctrine 2, Symfony used it for sometime now.
I think Doctrine is quite advanced and horrible to integrate into ZF.

Overall my experience was that everything is more easily integrated.
Symfony2 comes with build in twig engine that helped me a lot since you can inherit from actual views (Not just view classes) instead of only using partials.

Also, the routing system is way more flexible and advanced as far as i see it.

Comment: I integrated both Doctrine 1 and 2 into ZF1. Nothing horrible happened.

Comment: @akond would you say it was fairly easy to do? I integrated both doctrine1 & doctrine2 as well with ZF but i found it to be quite annoying. With symfony it is a piece of cake.